# Dunnett Test with two different factors in R

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

I am trying to conduct Dunnett test. I have two different factors: 1) group, 2) condition
I can run the code with one factor using this code

```
Dunnett <- glht(anova_growth,
                  linfct = mcp(group= "Dunnett"))

summary(Dunnett)
```

However I need to consider both of the factors, I try this code but it is not working:

```
Dunnett <- glht(anova_growth,
                  linfct = mcp(group*condition = "Dunnett"))

summary(Dunnett)
```

How can I perform a Dunnett with two factors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dunnett <- glht(anova_growth,
                linfct = mcp(group= "Dunnett") + mcp(condition = "Dunnett"))
summary(Dunnett)
```